# ADT - intel atom is not avialible to choose

Tags: java, android, adt, android-virtual-device

I've installed the HAXM from the SDK->extras in addtion from the SDK manager for 4.3 (Also tried for diff version with the same results)  the ARM and intel are installed and from extras.
when i create AVD in target there is just the ARM for the selected version ,I cannot choose the intel atom,way ?

I have restart the machine and the eclispse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install the intel atom implementation for the API version of your emulator

In the SDK Manager make sure that you have installed `Intel x86 Atom system image` subitem of the API version of your emulator.

Comment: HI ,I already do that but noting was changed,I cannot choose the intel atom in the drop down list...

Comment: @mileyH You need to donwload two things - one is a package in the Extras, one is associated with the API level of the emulator you want to run. The intel option will be available only for the api levels you have downloaded the intel package. I am almost certain you do not need to restart.

Comment: HI Boris,both of them are marked as instaledd... that's the problem. in addition I have installed the HAXM  from the SDK folder...

Comment: @mileyH Well maybe then as an aggressive experiment install everything listed under tools, extras and the api level of your emulator. I would not imagine you would need that, but at least that way you will not have a way to have missed something. Just to verify once again. Your problem is that you are not presented with the option to construct intel emulator?

Comment: yes,Im not able to choose when I create new AVD in the target -intel atom i see just the arm,currently as suggested by you Im installing everything under the API17 and extras

Comment: I've install evething and still not working :(,any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Install the corresponding API level x86 system image, note that x86 system image may not be available for all API levels.Also please make sure to install hot fix for HAXM depending on your host machine from [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/) It is important to install HAXM outside of the SDK manager too.